# "Haul down one's colours"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does it mean? I reckoned it was a set phrase of sort but couldn't find it. "Colours" must refer to a flag, right? It's hard to grasp the meaning still. All Quiet On The Western Front

> But we would have felt ridiculous had we **hauled down our colours**.

Comment: What's the rest of the context? "Colours" can refer to a flag, and "hauling down our colours" could mean "lowering our flag". Does that make sense in the context?

Comment: @gotube to me, it doesn't ‍♂️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lowering the colours is done to indicate submission or giving up. Here it means "give up" or "back down"

The German: "Aber wir wären uns lächerlich vorgekommen, wenn wir **klein beigegeben hätten**." doesn't mention "colours", so this is an interpretation by the translator.

http://www.thebellacademy.com/uploads/2/6/5/6/26569366/all_quiet_on_the_western_front_full_text.pdf

https://ivannikovairina.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/remarque_im_westen_nichts_neues_pdf.pdf